# postgresql query to generate report of ordered transaction numbers based on field - customerId

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.2

I have a customer transaction table in postgresql db with the columns below:

```
transactionId (primary)| customerId(int8)| transactionDate (timestamp)
1                        2                 2020-02-14
2                        3                 2020-03-08 
3                        1                 2020-02-06 //ignore
4                        2                 2020-02-10 // ignore
5                        2                 2020-03-24
6                        2                 2020-03-25
7                        2                 2020-02-12 //ignore (date < 13/02/2020)
```

I need to generate the report below, which has:

1. A timestamp of every transaction they've done since 13/02/2020 split out as 'Transaction1', 'Transaction2' and so on
2. Records should include the customerId as well.

How can I build the query to make the report shown below?

```
CustomerId| TransactionNo | TransactionDate
2            1               2020-02-14
2            2               2020-03-24
2            3               2020-03-25
3            1               2020-03-08
```

```
select
  customerId,
  transactionDate
from myTable where transactionDate > '2020-02-13'
order by
  customerId, transactionDate
```

How can I add the transactionNo, like 1,2,3?

Comment: Please show the results in a *tablular* format.

Comment: Postgres 9.2 and 9.3 are [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade now.

Answer (score 1):

[Window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/tutorial-window.html) can help you to achieve re-ordered transaction numbers in this format

```
SELECT 
    customerId, 
    rank() OVER (PARTITION BY customerId ORDER BY transactionDate) as transactionNo,
    transactionDate 
FROM 
    myTable 
WHERE 
    transactionDate > '2020-02-13' 
ORDER BY
    customerId, transactionDate
```

The rank function will provide the set of ordered numbers i.e. 1,2,3 over the partition (i.e. logically group by, you will still have each record in the dataset) customerId and ordered by transactionDate.

Thus providing the desired result of

```
CustomerId| TransactionNo | TransactionDate
2            1               2020-02-14
2            2               2020-03-24
2            3               2020-03-25
3            1               2020-03-08
```